# Open new tab\window in Salesforce Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

We are trying to convert to the Salesforce lightning experience. One of the recent roadblocks is as simple as opening a new window or tab.  The previously defined Java script button is now a lightning component used in a quick action.  The need is to click a button, execute some validation and render a Visual force page as a PDF.  When we use the Salesforce recommended "force:navigateToURL" the PDF is opened in the same window as the button originated.  We would like to use a familiar 'window.open' but that is not recommended. If anyone has an idea how to open a new window\tab when a quick action button is clicked that would be great.

This is the component code we are currently trying to use:

```
var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
urlEvent.setParams({
"url": '/apex/RenderAsPDFVisualforce?Id=' + recordId,
"target": "_blank"
});`
```

Comment: How did you achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

That should work. You just need to call urlEvent.fire(); as well.

Comment: Lightning Experience, non-console app, opened in same tab/window, but worked for my use case.  Thanks to OP and @Ryan Villamin!

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a console app ( recommended ) , you can use lightning workspaceApi

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_js_lightning_syntax.htm

- openTab method: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_opentab.htm

Add the following line in your quickAction component

```
<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
```

Then you can request to open a new tab with your url

```
    var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    workspaceAPI.openTab({
        url: '/apex/RenderAsPDFVisualforce?Id=' + recordId,
        focus: true
    }).then(function(response) {
          // actions to do after opening tab if necessary
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```